# socket.error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer in Ubuntu and Android

Tags: python, android, sockets, ubuntu, kivy

I have worked with Kivy(Android). I connect to the WiFi module(ESP8266) through the socket:

```
host = '192.168.4.1'
port = 8888
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
s.connect((host, port))
```

I send "ON" as part of the program,`s.send(str.encode("ON"))` but I get the following error:`[Errno 104] Connection reset by peer.`Exactly the same code works properly in Windows, but doesn't work in Ubuntu and Android. How can I fix the error?

Comment: What has Ubuntu to do with with an ESP? Or with Android?

Comment: I made the connection between Ubuntu and ESP8266 through socket. I will send a string ("ON") from Ubuntu to ESP8266.